# How do you set a program as a service in Linux (Debian) but have it switched off by default?

Tags: debian, tomcat

When you install Alfresco, it gives you an option of having it installed as a service or not.

If you install it as a service, the service starts up on booting but since it's using Tomcat it's too heavy to leave as a background program. In addition, it takes a lot longer to stop than Apache.

Therefore, I would like to keep it as a service but have it set to off by default so all I need to do is type `sudo service alfresco start`.

While I can leave it set-up not as a service and write a bash script or two, I'd like to learn more about how "services" work in Linux. Apache's not a problem but it would be nice to know where its service parameters are stored and how you can change these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'general' approach would be

```
$ sudo update-rc.d -f servicename remove
```

to remove the *servicename* from any runlevel to start automatically.

To re-enable the defaults, do

```
$ sudo update-rc.d servicename defaults
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [sysv-rc-conf](http://sysv-rc-conf.sourceforge.net/) to manage [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Debian_Linux) (configure which services are supposed to be started at which runlevels).

It is quite simple:

1. Install it: `sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`
2. Run it: `sudo sysv-rc-conf`
3. Mark your service to be started on desired runlevels (2, 3, 4 and 5 are regular boot, 0 is shutdown, 6 is reboot). Use keyboard arrows to navigate and `space` key to toggle a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Debian ships with SysVinit. Which services are executed in which runlevels is controlled through symbolic links in `/etc/initN.d` (N = 0 to 6, with 2–5 being the normal runlevels; S is for services started at boot time). See [Dmitry Vasilyanov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56206) and [gertvdijk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56252)'s answers for ways of configuring these symbolic links.

I like to use the [`file-rc`](http://packages.debian.org/file-rc) package, which replaces the symbolic links with a simple text file `/etc/runlevel.conf`.

If you're going to turn off a lot of services, or if you want to prevent a service from starting when it's installed or upgraded (a known issue on Debian), you can define a local service start policy. Write a script called [`/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`](https://raw.github.com/formorer/file-rc/master/README.policy-rc.d) that implements the [init script policy](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=invoke-rc.d) of your choice. See `/usr/share/doc/sysv-rc/README.policy-rc.d` on your system for details. Implementing a full policy is a bit of work, but you can make simple cases work; for example, if the script just contains `exit 101`, then no init script will ever be executed (this is convenient for systems installed in a chroot).