# Systemd - set service disabled by default

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I have just installed tor: 
`sudo apt-get install tor`. 
 After that, I rebooted and ran `sudo systemctl status tor` and noticed that it is active running. So I suppose it is enable by default. How to setup it in such a way that it will only run when I `sudo systemctl start tor`

**Edit**: I don't agree marking this question as duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56195/how-do-you-set-a-program-as-a-service-in-linux-debian-but-have-it-switched-off) since my question is about `Systemd` and the allegedly duplicate is in `SysVinit`. The way to enable/disable services is clearly difference between both.

Comment: I believe that the questioner is asking how to arrange things such that _installing a package does not automatically enable and also start the service_. The questioner is far from the first Debian user to ask this.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56195/ for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set it up to run only when needed:

1. disable it:

   - `sudo systemctl disable tor`
2. To run when needed just do:

   - `sudo systemctl start tor`
3. To stop:

   - `sudo systemctl stop tor`